# Do mineral glass lenses on sunglasses block 100% of harmful UV radiations?

Tags: radiation, ophthalmology

I have also come across sunglasses fitted with "mineral glass lenses" which claim to filter 100% of UVA and UVB without the need for a UV coating, e.g.:

- [Otis](https://us.vuarnet.com/blogs/frequently-asked-questions/how-do-my-vuarnet-sunglasses-protect-my-eyes):

> OTIS standard lenses are all made from mineral glass that is scratch-resistant, environmentally friendly and distortion free. **They have a fixed tinting that won’t peel or fade over time and block 100% of harmful UVA, UVB and HEV light**, providing superior protection from solar damage, while maintaining true colour and depth perception.

- [Vuarnet grey mineral lenses](https://us.vuarnet.com/blogs/mineral-lenses/grey-lenses):

> Treatments
>
> - Mineral glass offering the clearest vision
>   [...]
>
> Protection
>
> - Category 3
> - **UV Protection: 100%**
> - Infra-Red: Up to 90%
> - Visible light absorption: Up to 90%
> - Blue Light Filter: Up to 93%

These lenses don't have any surface treatment other than an anti-reflective coating on the interior.

Do mineral glass lenses protect against UV radiation?

Comment: This feels like a physics question as much as anything: a visible tint is, by definition, an absorption (or reflection) of frequencies that are visible to our eyes; absorption of frequencies that aren't visible to our eyes is by definition not visible. So a lens might appear completely transparent to "visible light", but filter most UV frequencies; and another might filter some visible frequencies (thus, appear tinted) but not block any UV frequencies (which we can't see).

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/) I focussed the question onto the main claims, and avoided getting distracted by tints, your understanding of polycarbonates, etc.

Comment: Seems like an easy thing to test.

Comment: Thanks @Oddthinking, but the claim I was confused about was the one being made in the articles I had linked about tint colour not having any bearing on UV protection. as I've seen amber-coloured glass being used to store light-sensitive materials, .

Comment: @user51462 I don't see that claim being made in the articles. They don't say that tint doesn't matter, they just say that their glasses use mineral glass, and that they block UV. 
Any glass inherently blocks a lot of UV radiation  regardless of tinting or treatment. Glass is pretty much opaque to UVB in particular. UVA is blocked to a lesser degree based on various factors such as lamination, tinting, coatings, etc.  Can you clarify the actual claim you're questioning?

Comment: Easy to disprove: in science nothing is ever 100% certain.

Comment: @barbecue: That's because I removed some of the claims to focus the question. Looks like it needs another edit.

Comment: @user51462: When you say you've seen amber-coloured glass to store light-sensitive materials: amber coloured glass clearly doesn't block yellow wave length and does block blue wavelengths (by High School science), so the material isn't *light* sensitive; it must be blue light sensitive. Whether the glass blocks UV wavelengths depends on the glass. So there is no notable claim here that visible glass colour affects its UV transmissibility. Everything seems to point toward it being unrelated.

Comment: @user51462 Imagine someone claimed "red cars are faster", it would be easy to show that paint colour is not a key factor in the speed of the car. Saying "I've seen red Ferraris that were really fast" doesn't change that. In the same way, "I've seen amber glass which protects against UV" (even if true) would not change the statement "tint colour is not directly related to UV protection" - the glass could be tinted amber *and coincidentally* made of a substance that blocks UV. Again, remember that you can't _see_ whether UV is blocked with the naked eye - the human eye isn't equipped to do so.

Answer (score 6):

Most glasses block some amount of UV light, particularly the "harder" UV like UVC and UVB. UVC is not really relevant in the context of sunlight at normal altitudes, as the atmosphere, in particular ozone in the upper layers, filters it out.

Now, for the UVB and UVA parts that e.g. suncream needs to block to protect your skin; what about the glass that protects your eyes?

Let's first define the UV-regions:

- UV-A goes from about 315-390 nm, has longer wavelengths and less energy and does not penetrate as deeply into tissue
- UV-B goes from about 280-315 nm, has shorter wavelengths and thus more energy and does penetrate deeper into tissue, can cause damage there (sunburn, skin cancer)
- UV-C 100-280 nm, really high energy UV. Very damaging to tissue but usually not an issue with sunlight.

If we look at the following chart from [Edmund Optics](https://www.edmundoptics.de/knowledge-center/application-notes/optics/optical-glass/) (a reputable seller of optical equipment and related fields)

[image: transmission chart from Edmund Optics]

we see transmission curves for different types of glass. As you can see, all of them start to let less and less light through the deeper we go into the UV. In particular, B270 seems to be a common mineral glass used in corrective glasses. It lets about 90% of 360 nm (which is UV-A light) through, and about 50% of 320 nm light, which is almost in the UV-B region.

So it lets **some** UV light through, but not all of it. That means that a ordinary, untinted pair of glasses is still better sunlight protection than no glasses, but by far not as good as sunglasses that follow the ANSI Z87.1 or UV400 guideline (explained [here](https://www.uvex-safety.com/en/product-group/uvex-uv-400/)), which lets virtually no light below 380 or 400 nm pass through.

Addendum: for your application - you said you saw *"sunglasses fitted with "mineral glass lenses"*" - I think the white, untinted glass alone would not necessarily offer enough UV protection, depending on the glass type. As we can see, there are glasses that offer more UV blocking, but these glasses are not really that common to the best of my knowledge. You didn't tell us if the glasses were also tinted, which, again depending on the technique used, might block UV. Your best bet is to look for any kind of certification according to respectable governing bodies like the FDA in the United States or the CE sign in the European Union.

Comment: Also it would be useful to annotate the chart to show visible, UV-A and UV-B bands. But thanks for the great answer.

Comment: I realize it's no longer part of the question, but one might also point out that dark lenses (traditional sun glasses) don't necessarily block UV. By not blocking UV, they actually cause more damage than non-tinted glasses (or no glasses at all) since they block the colours that cause the pupils to contract, allowing more light into the eye than if one didn't wear them.

Comment: Aren't most glasses lenses made from polycarbonate or pmma these days? They absorb UV pretty completely up to 300-350nm iirc

Comment: @RayButterworth: [citation-needed]

Comment: @Oddthinking [does this count](https://www.loxleyopticians.com/sunglasses-everything-you-need-to-know-about-tinted-lenses/)? Also [this one](https://www.columbiadoctors.org/news/sunglasses-and-your-eyes)

Comment: @fyrepenguin: This isn't so much convincing me of the claim (the original question had references too) so much as saying "Stop using comments to propagate unreferenced claims on this site that is dedicated to the opposite."